# Python "requests" module truncating responses

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

When I use the python `requests` module, calling `requests.get(url)`, I have found that the response from the url is being truncated.

```
import requests

url = 'https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ'
response = requests.get(url)
print response.text
```

The response I get from the URL is being truncated. Is there a way to get `requests` to retrieve the full set of data and *not* truncate it?

**Note:** The given URL is a public transport feed which puts out a huge quantity data during the peak of day.

Comment: `requests` itself does not truncate data, no. Have you verified that the server is sending correct headers?

Comment: When I load that URL, `len(response.content)` matches `response.headers['content-length']`.

Comment: So I did a check where I did a request via the above script, then also did a manual download from the url myself. The manual feed was considerably longer then the one return via the script.

Comment: It might not be truncating it anymore as the vehicle numbers have dropped considerably, from its peak number.

Comment: Any HTTP server is free to *completely alter* its response from second to second. It is a black box, we don't know what criteria it uses to serve content. Most likely `requests` request differs from your browser request in some way that makes the server respond differently. That could be any number of factors; check for differences in query parameters, headers, and the time of day.

Comment: But there is nothing *inherent in `requests` here*. This is a server behaviour issue. You may well get a different response again if you used `curl`. Or `urllib2`, or a library in a different programming language. Or even if you requested the data from a different IP address.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then the bug must be somewhere else in the broader script this belongs to.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as "can't reproduce".

Comment: Fire up a packet capture utility like Wireshark and verify whether the server is actually truncating the response, or whether the data is getting lost somewhere on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. The problem is not your Python code. It might be PyCharm or Utility you are using - The console has a buffer limit. You may have to increase that to see your full response.

Refer to this article for more help:
[Increase output buffer when running or debugging in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355460/increase-output-buffer-when-running-or-debugging-in-pycharm)

Answer (score -1):

Add "gzip":true to your request options.
That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Do you mean 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'?
Still, looking at the discussion above, this does not seem the solution to the issue at hand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).