# Increase output buffer when running or debugging in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

My console output is exceeding PyCharm's buffer size in the Run output window. So when I scroll to the top after a test completes, I can't get all the way to the start of the console output. I can run the tests in an external terminal window and see all the output, but the integration with PyCharm is handy.

Is there a way to increase the buffer size of the PyCharm run output so I can retain all my logging output and scroll right to the top?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the `idea.cycle.buffer.size` setting within the `bin/idea.properties` file within the installation folder (or within the Application package on OS X).

Setting:

```
idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
```

disables the cyclic buffer.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-idea-properties.html for details.

Comment: One nuance - this extends the buffer of the Run/Debug/etc output, as the OP requests, but it does not not increase the buffer of the Terminal output (where I have Celery threads logging copiously).

Comment: @Chris - is there a place to increase the terminal buffer?

Comment: Works in CLion 2017.3.1 as well.

Answer (score 92):

You can increase the size of the console buffer in the **application Preference**:

[image: How to increase the buffer size in a nutshell]

Comment: This option doesn't seem to affect the console buffer in the debugger.

Comment: @DavidParks it seems affect the console buffer in the debugger now. Anyway, point is for anyone stumbling across this: Give it a try anyway!

Comment: Works on Pycharm CE 2020.3

Comment: Works like a charm on PyCharm CE 2020.3 for Windows as well!

Answer (score 19):

At least as of PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3, IntelliJ does not recommend editing `bin/idea.properties`.  From [the URL mentioned above](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-idea-properties.html):

> The file idea.properties, located in the bin directory of the IntelliJ
>   IDEA installation folder, should not be edited. Instead of editing the
>   original idea.properties, create file idea.properties in the location
>   specified below, open it for editing and add the required properties.

I discovered an easy way to do that: from PyCharm, run Help->Edit Custom Properties.  This opens an editor window on an empty file where you can make and save options.  In my case the file was saved at `%USERPROFILE%\.PyCharm50\idea.properties`.

Also, rather than completely disable the circular buffer,  you may want to increase it from its default of 1024k, e.g. to `idea.cycle.buffer.size=2048`

Though it's apparently missing in JetBrains' documentation, I found it necessary to exit and restart PyCharm before this took effect with PyCharm CE 5.0.3 under Windows 7 Pro.

BTW, the `bin/idea.properties` file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\bin\idea.properties` on my system) is still a good place to find out what settings may be edited and their current values.

Comment: Actually, directly increasing buffer in the global bin/idea.properties - did not have effect on my console in PyCharm (Linux). Adding it to Custom Properties - did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers worked for me to increase the size of the Run Tool Window buffer in community build 2021.1.

Using Help/Edit Custom properties and then adding the line:

```
terminal.buffer.max.lines.count = 20000000
```

Is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 6):

For **PyCharm 2021.3** the following worked for me:

File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Console -->

Then check "Override console cycle buffer size (1024 KB)"

Change that values to whatever you need

[image]