# Pycharm Python - Display Full Print

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

How do I configure Pycharm to display full print?

I am getting

```
print df

A                 9               9            9        9
B                 9               9            9        9
C                 9               9            9        9
...                         ...             ...          ...      ...
G                 9               9            9        9
H                 9               9            9        9
I                 9               9            9        9
```

but I want

```
A                 9               9            9        9
B                 9               9            9        9
C                 9               9            9        9
D                 9               9            9        9
E                 9               9            9        9
F                 9               9            9        9
G                 9               9            9        9
H                 9               9            9        9
I                 9               9            9        9
```

I want to avoid truncating the output

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355460/increase-output-buffer-when-running-or-debugging-in-pycharm

Comment: yes. thanks very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-print an entire Pandas Series / DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/pretty-print-an-entire-pandas-series-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

If you're this has the same behaviour in simple terminal/console, consider configuring [pandas options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) itself.

Answer (score 1):

`print(df.to_string())` should work.