# How to avoid truncation when printing large objects in python debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pdb

When printing objects with many fields or large `repr` or `str` strings, I noticed in the PyCharm debugger that they frequently get truncated. For instance if we have

```
a = list(range(1000))
b = 1+2  # set breakpoint here
```

and in the interactive debugger call `print(a)` we get following output (newlines manually inserted), where the string is truncated and an ellipsis is added.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89,
 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 
127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 
162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179,
 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 
197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214,
 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,...
```

Is it possible to avoid this and get the full string?

---

Here the actual screenshot for demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the text truncated? In the debugger tool window? Or is it the terminal, console, run tool window, etc...? Because each of those windows has very different properties.

Comment: @bad_coder Thanks, I should have stated that: I'm referring to PyCharm's debugging console.

Comment: @flawr you mean [this window here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#start-debugger-session) right? And inside that window the console? Or just the debugger itself? Or the [console tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html)? Sorry to be asking but as you can see the names overlap and each tool window has very different settings... In questions like this one a screenshot is priceless to let us know exactly which tab in which tool window is meant.

Comment: @bad_coder I'm sorry for my bad phrasing, I meant the console of the debugger, not the console-tool-window. I have added a screenshot!

Comment: @flawr no problem, it's very difficult to distinguish because of the overlap in names. I think [this post likely has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610574) if not let us know in the comments and we'll look into it.

Comment: @bad_coder Thank you for the tip, unfortunately it didn't change anything for me even after restarting/turning that option on/off and changing its value. Thank you for your help and all your suggestions!

Comment: Maybe it's [PY-53807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53807) I haven't tested all the possible solutions in the previously linked post.